# Look above and below a particular cell for the value 0, then sum values between upper and lower 0

Tags: python, excel, ms-access, sum

I am trying to say at cell B3, look above the cell and below the cell until a 0 value is found, then, sum the values between 0s.

ex) B1=0,B2=.01 B3=.01, B4=.02, B5=0

So, at B3, look above until B2, look below until B5, sum B3 and B4, return .04.  This doesn't need to be done in excel, I can move the data to other programs.

Comment: Are you trying to do this with Python, an Excel formula, in MS Access...?  What does ArcPy have to do with this? What have you tried?

Comment: I was using index match in excel, had tried in python, and also tried an arcpy cell check to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in C2,

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(14, 6, ROW($1:2)/(B$1:B2=0), 1)):INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B)))/(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99, B:B))=0), 1)))
```

This will dynamically find the end of the numbers in column B.

[image]

Comment: This also works! Totally different solution, same result, thank you!

Comment: I understand the index, match, and aggregate functions, as well as using large and small, what is the purpose/what does match 1E+99 say?

Comment: index(b:b, match(1e99, b:b)) supplies the cell with the last number in column B. Since AGGREGATE uses cyclic processing like an array formula, you want to avoid using full column references. You don't want to look for a zero all the way down to the bottom of the worksheet, only as far as hte numbers in column B extend.

Answer (score 2):

This is for **Excel solution**:

[image]

You can use this **array formula** (click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> together):

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$1:$B$6,MATCH(0,$B$1:$B$6,0)):INDEX($B$1:$B$6,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$6=0,ROW($B$1:$B$6)-ROW(B1)+1),2)))
```

This is use `INDEX/MATCH` to find the first 0 and `INDEX/SMALL` to find the second 0, and then use the `SUM` to add up the range.

Comment: This worked beautifully, I wasn't using an array formula before, and didn't know about INDEX/SMALL, thank you!

Comment: ian0411, just so I understand a little better, this says: 
INDEX($B$1:$B$6 return the values in column B1-B6
MATCH(0,$B$1:$B$6,0), lookup in B1-B6 starting and ending with a 0
INDEX($B$1:$B$6 return the values in column B1-B6
SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$6=0, lookup in B1-B6 retreiving the lowest value
ROW($B$1:$B$6)-ROW(B1)+1
,2

is this correct? I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the small portion.  Also, does this return the last 0, or the "closest" 0 in the column?

Comment: The sum is basically `B2:B5`.  But `B1` and `B6` are zeros anyway.  Think what I did is `=SUM(INDEX(find first 0):INDEX(find second 0))`

Comment: The `SMALL` part is to find the row number and I want to return the row number where the 2nd zero is.

Comment: No problem at all.  My pleasure.